# Qt Virtual Keyboard is a black screen when compiling with msys2 mingw64 package

Tags: qt, qml, mingw-w64, virtual-keyboard, qtvirtualkeyboard

I making an application that uses the virtual keyboard from qt.
I have built it using two different compilers

1. Using the bundled mingw compiler that comes with Qt Creator 4.14.2 using Qt 5.15.2
2. Using the mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5 package with msys2, which is also Qt 5.15.2

Here is a simple reproducable example project showing the issue

.pro file

```
QT += quick virtualkeyboard svg

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

TextField {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}

InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel
    z: 89
    y: active ? parent.height - height : parent.height
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
}
```

}

The first compiles and runs without any issues, looking like this:

[image]

and the second compiles and runs like this:

[image]

The only difference is the build settings, where one has the first toolchain selected and the second has the other.

The msys2 toolchain is the one I use normally and it runs any other application and library I use without any issues.

I also added QT_PLUGIN_DEBUG=1 and can verify that all libraries are loaded and accounted for in both toolchains.

Comment: Are there no errors? Are you running it from Creator or the command line? Try running it after setting `QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.virtualkeyboard*=true`. That might print something useful.

Comment: No errors. Setting the loggin rule as you suggested didn't provide any added output in the terminal, does it require me to add additional debug logging in the code? QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.virtualkeyboard*=true gave one output, which was the the syntax was wrong. I changed it to QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.virtualkeyboard.trace=true, which I think is correct?